# Prove the Boundedness of a Self-Adjoint Operator in a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, closed-graph

this is the question and my attempted answer below. I would be happy if you could please proofread and let me know any suggestions if you spot any errors! :D

Question: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A: H \rightarrow H$ be linear. Assume that
$$
(A x, y)=(x, A y) \quad \text { for every } x, y \in H .
$$

Show that $A$ is bounded.

My Answer: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A: H \rightarrow H$ be linear. Assume that
$$
(A x, y)=(x, A y) \quad \text { for every } x, y \in H
$$

We need to show that $A$ is bounded.

To use the Closed Graph Theorem, we will first show that $G(A)$ is closed. This means that if $\left(x_n, A x_n\right)$ converges to $(x, y)$ in $H \times H$, then $(x, y)$ is in $G(A)$, i.e., $y=A x$.

Let $\left(x_n, A x_n\right)$ be a sequence in $G(A)$ that converges to $(x, y)$ in $H \times H$. This implies that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $A x_n \rightarrow y$ in $H$.

Now, because $H$ is a Hilbert space, it has an inner product that is continuous. Hence, for every $z \in H$, we have
$$
\left(A x_n, z\right) \rightarrow(y, z) \text { and }\left(x_n, A z\right) \rightarrow(x, A z) .
$$

By the linearity and symmetry of the inner product, and by the given property of $A$, we have
$$
\left(A x_n, z\right)=\left(x_n, A z\right) \text { for all } n .
$$

Taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we get
$$
(y, z)=(x, A z) .
$$

Since $z$ is arbitrary, we can replace $z$ by $A^* z^{\downarrow}$, where $A^*$ is the adjoint operator of $A$, obtaining
$$
\left(y, A^* z\right)=\left(x, A A^* z\right)
$$

By the definition of the adjoint, we have
$$
(A y, z)=\left(A A^* x, z\right)
$$

This implies that $A y=A A^* x$.

Given that the inner product $(x, y)$ is equal to $(A x, A y)$ for every $x$ and $y$, and that $\left(x_n, A x_n\right)$ converges to $(x, y)$, it follows that $(x, y) \in G(A)$, thus $G(A)$ is closed.

Now, by the Closed Graph Theorem, because $G(A)$ is closed, $A$ must be continuous, which in the context of a Hilbert space means that $A$ is bounded.

Hence, we have shown that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: It is really hard to read because you are using the same notation for pairs and for the inner product, for the latter it might be better to use $\langle x, y \rangle$.